# Transfer data from two cells on one sheet to two cells on a different sheet in the same Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I know the code has to include the words "destination" and "source" but that is about it. I want to move data from Sheet2 in cell I7 to Sheet1 in cell E5, and I want to move data from Sheet2 in cell C8 to E6. Do I have to include the actual sheet name in the code or is the sheet number sufficient?

Sheet 1 is the dashboard sheet. I want all data entered in sheet 2 to appear in sheet 1 at the touch of a button. And after all the data is transferred to sheet 1, I want sheet 2 to have zero data there.
Can someone please help me with this code, I am a newb at VBA/Macro.

Comment: I used this but tried to tweak it to apply to my project:Sub transfer()
Dim strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String, sourceData As String
strSourceSheet = "profile list"
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Activate
sourceData = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(30, 37).Value
strDestinationSheet = "RADIANT OPTO-ELECTRONICS CORP."
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Activate
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(C, 11) = sourceData
End Sub

Comment: As stated, please include code in your question, not in the comments. It cannot be formatted properly in the comments.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I7").Value` - That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
'declare alias

Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks("nameoftheworkbook.xlsm")
Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("nameofthesheet")

Dim wks2 As Excel.Worksheet
Set wks2 = wkb.Worksheets("nameofthesheet")

'copy value

wks.Range("E5").Value = wks2.Range("I7").Value
```